# How to pass data to different screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I need to pass data from one screen to anothre, an main screen loads and then loads the data from a mock api, it sets the state with providerData, then navigation gets created. I want to be able to use the data i got in the ProviderDetailScreen.js in ProviderOverview.js

Here is ProviderDetailsScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StatusBar, View} from 'react-native';
import ProviderOverview from './ProviderOverview';
import ProviderServicesList from './ProviderServicesList';
import NavigationbarHeaderWithExpandedImage from '../components/NavigationbarHeaderWithExpandedImage';
import TopTabbarComponent from '../components/TopTabbarComponent';
import mockApi from '../mockApi';

const ProviderDetailScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const [providerData, setProviderData] = React.useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);

  //navigation setup
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      header: ({scene, previous}) => {
        return (
          <NavigationbarHeaderWithExpandedImage
            scene={scene}
            previous={previous}
            navigation={navigation}
            backgroundImage={providerData?.profile?.backgroundImage}
          />
        );
      },
    });
  }, [navigation, providerData]);

  //get results from API
  const getServices = React.useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await mockApi.get('/Provider/Profile');
      if (res.ok && res.body.data) {
        // use this data in overview and service list
        setLoading(false);
        setProviderData(res.body.data);
      } else {
        throw new Error('Unable to retrieve profile');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.warn('here');
    getServices();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
      <TopTabbarComponent
        items={[
          {
            title: 'Overview',
            component: ProviderOverview,
          },
          {
            title: 'Services',
            component: ProviderServicesList,
          },
          {
            title: 'Reviews',
            component: View,
          },
        ]}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ProviderDetailScreen;
```

Here is The ToTabbarComponent.js that created a tab for each item in providerdetailsscreen

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import {PRIMARY, WHITE, INACTIVE_TINT_COLOR, ACCENT} from '../lib/colors';
import fonts from '../lib/fonts';
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const TopTabbarComponent = ({items}) => {
  const tabs = () => {
    let tabs = [];

    //  loop to create tabs
    for (const [index, item] of items.entries()) {
      tabs.push(
        <Tab.Screen
          name={item.title}
          title={item.title}
          component={item.component}
          key={index}
        />,
      );
    }
    return tabs;
  };
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: WHITE,
        labelStyle: [styles.labelStyle, fonts.medium],
        inactiveTintColor: INACTIVE_TINT_COLOR,
        style: styles.style,
        indicatorStyle: styles.indicatorStyle,
      }}>
      {tabs()}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabBarOptions: {},
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  indicatorStyle: {
    backgroundColor: ACCENT,
    height: 2,
  },
  style: {
    backgroundColor: PRIMARY,
  },
});

export default TopTabbarComponent;
```

Here is the ProviderOverview.js where i want to use that data that gets set in ProviderDetailsScreen.js

```
//WANT TO USE DATA HERE
       import React from 'react';
    import {StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Text} from 'react-native';
    import MediumText from '../components/MediumText';
    
    const ProviderOverview = ({navigation}) => {
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <View>
            <MediumText onPress={() => navigation.push('PROVIDER_MESSAGE')}>
              Send a message
            </MediumText>
          </View>
          <View></View>
        </ScrollView>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    });
    export default ProviderOverview;
```

I am still learning: Things i have tried:

In providerDetailsscreen i tried to set providerdata for each item, i tried setting a test var with some string to see if i can get it in ProviderOverview. But providerOverview only has Navigation prop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

ProviderDetailsScreen.js

```
<TopTabbarComponent
        items={[
          {
            title: 'Overview',
            component: ProviderOverview,
            providerData: providerData, // set providerData to ProviderOverview
          },
          {
            title: 'Services',
            component: ProviderServicesList,
          },
          {
            title: 'Reviews',
            component: View,
          },
        ]}
      />
```

TopTabbarComponent

```
//  loop to create tabs
    for (const [index, item] of items.entries()) {
      const CompView = item.component;
      const providerData = item.providerData || {};
      
      tabs.push(
       <Tab.Screen name={item.title} title={item.title} key={index}>
         {(props) => <CompView  {...props} {...providerData} />}
       </Tab.Screen>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is what i was missing, the TopTabbarComponent the {props} that gets passed in like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigation props
`this.props.navigation.navigate('MyData', {data: data,});`
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#navigate

Or add redux to your project https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started